# about the usage of the word "have"

Tags: grammar

Is "I have all things memorized" the same as "I have all things which are memorized"?

Or does it mean that I make things memorized?

Comment: We need context. The first sentence makes little sense and the second makes no sense. Are you trying to say, "I'm memorizing everything?"

Comment: The sentence mean ➡ you have been memorized all things by some one.(memorize means -To learn to remember something)(In this context it might implies— Someone has tried to make you learn to remember all things.

Comment: What are you trying to say? Do you mean you cause things to be memorized, or that you have memorized them yourself?

Comment: @gotube  that you have memorized them yourself

Comment: @Sam Can "someone" be "I" too?

Comment: No, If it's **you** then you should say :—I have  memorized all things.

Answer (score 0):

'I **have** all things memorized' (I don't memorize all things. I ask someone else to memorize all things.) 'Have' is a causative verb.

We use **have** + object + past participle when we talk about someone doing something for us.

She **had** the car washed. (I did not wash the car. I paid someone to wash the car.)

I **have** my hair cut. (I do not cut my hair. Someone cuts my hair.)

He **had** the house painted. (Somebody painted the house.)

Comment: So Is "I have all things memorized" different from "I memorized all things"?

Comment: 도라에몽 Yes, 'I  all things memorized' is different from 'I  all things'.

Comment: This is a possible interpretation, but it is a **much** less likely interpretation than _I have memorized all things_.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, what you mean is something like, "*I have all **these** things memorized*", so I'm going to add "these" to your example sentences.

The first sentence means you have completed the job of memorizing all of these things, and now you know them all by heart.

The second sentence means you have all of the things *that someone has memorized*. It's unclear in what sense you "have" those things, and it's unclear who memorized them.

So no, the sentences are not the same.

(1) "I have these things memorized" is roughly the same as, (2) "I have memorized these things". The only difference is that (1) necessarily means you know them right now, but (2) could mean (A) you know them all right now, or (B) you memorized them all at some time in the past, but you don't know them all right now. In the right context, the meaning is unambiguous:

> "Can you play this song without looking at the sheet music?"
> "Yes, I have memorized it." (meaning A)

> "Have you ever tried memorizing the digits of pi?"
> "I have memorized 50 digits, but that was years ago and I don't think I can remember them all anymore." (meaning B)